# Java JSON Library getString() by variable value

Tags: java, android, json

Okay, so I'm just getting started with Java so this might be pretty newbie question. Anyway, what I'm trying to accomplish is to parse a piece of JSON using Java's `org.json.JSONObject` library.

So I have this line which grabs the value of the JSON just fine:

```
amountValue = jsonData.getString("USD");
```

But what the value of that JSON element is different, based on the API Request that was made, so I have the currency code stored into another variable which I've tried to use like this:

```
amountValue = jsonData.getString(v_from);
```

Where `v_from` is the value of a spinner:

```
String v_from = fromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

But when trying this, I'm getting `NULL` . Any ideas?

Comment: share some code so we can help you...

Comment: Is amountValue a String or a Double?

Comment: It is actually a String, I have copied the wrong line of code. Revised the Question.

Comment: K. And have you verified the value of `v_from` is a key in the JSON?

Comment: Post your json data and show how this data is added in the adapter please.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I've checked that, the value coresponds to the JSON key. Do you know if  there is a way to access the key with numeric indexes ?

Comment: You can only access json arrays with numeric indices, not objects